# jQuery .Animate Opacity and .FadeOut/In Both Not Working Inside SetInterval

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I trying to make what appears to the user to be an image fader. A string of images fade into each other. All the solutions that I found were complex, and normally required an  for every image. I've come up with what should be a simple solution. It's working 90% on Firefox/Chrome/IE11 on Windows. On Android Chrome it's having issues.

Basically my idea is, I have two divs, absolutely positioned, one on top of the other. Both start with a background, sized to cover. The top one fades out, revealing the bottom one, and at the end of the animation, the background-image of the top one (current hidden) is changed to image 3. After a pause, it fades back in, and the background-image of the bottom one is changed to image 4. This repeats indefinitely.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow-top"></div>
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow-bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    display:block;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#slideshow-top {
    z-index:-5;
    background-image:url(http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-1.jpg);
}
#slideshow-bottom {
    z-index:-10;
    background-image:url(http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-2.jpg);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var url_array = [
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-1.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-2.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-3.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-4.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-5.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-6.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-7.jpg',
    'http://www.walldoze.com/images/full/2013/12/04/wallpapers-desktop-winter-nature-x-wallpaper-backgrounds-natureabstract-designs-interesting-hd-19045.jpg'
];
var count = 1;

setInterval(function() {

    if (count%2) { // Fade In

        jQuery('#slideshow-top').animate({opacity:0}, '200000', function() {

            jQuery('#slideshow-top').css('background-image','url('+url_array[count]+')');

        });

    }

    else {  //Fade Out

        jQuery('#slideshow-top').animate({opacity:1}, '200', function() {

            jQuery('#slideshow-bottom').css('background-image','url('+url_array[count]+')');

        });
    }

    count = (count == url_array.length-1 ? 0 : count + 1);

}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eXy9/

As seen in the Fiddle above, this mostly works. However, it seems to ignore the length of the animation. Using .fadeOut has the same effect. I've tried going from 200 to 20000, and there doesn't seem to be a difference.

I'm not sure if this is tied into the other issue, which is that on Android (Galaxy S4, Chrome, Android 4.x), the animation doesn't occur at all. It simply changes images. Any ideas?

EDIT: Jan 10 - Timing problem is fixed, but the main issue (Android) is still unsolved. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval keeps going, so when increasing the animation speed, you have increase the interval speed as well.
The way you've built this, you should always keep the speed of both animations equal to the interval, or if you need a delay, increase the interval compared to the animations so it at least has a higher number than the highest number used in the animations.

The reason changing the speed doesn't work at all for you, is because **it should be integers, not strings**, so you have to do

```
jQuery('#slideshow-top').animate({opacity:0}, 200000, function() {...
 //                                             ^^  no quotes
```

I would do something like this

```
var url_array = [
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-1.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-2.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-3.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-4.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-5.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-6.jpg',
    'http://www.andymercer.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/slider-7.jpg',
    'http://www.walldoze.com/images/full/2013/12/04/wallpapers-desktop-winter-nature-x-wallpaper-backgrounds-natureabstract-designs-interesting-hd-19045.jpg'];
var count = 1;

var speed = 2000,
    delay = 1000;

$.each(url_array, function(source) { // preload
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = source;
});


setInterval(function () {
    if (count % 2) { // Fade In
        jQuery('#slideshow-top').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, speed, function () {
            jQuery('#slideshow-top').css('background-image', 'url(' + url_array[count] + ')');
        });

    } else { //Fade Out

        jQuery('#slideshow-top').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, speed, function () {
            jQuery('#slideshow-bottom').css('background-image', 'url(' + url_array[count] + ')');
        });
    }
    count = (count == url_array.length - 1 ? 0 : count + 1);
}, speed + delay);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eXy9/1/)

Comment: Good catch on the strings vs integers. That's gotten the different speed issue working. I will be able to check how it works on the mobile browser later today as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well it's still not working on the S4 that I'm using to test. Not sure why. Anyone else?

Comment: I'm setting this as the answer, even though only part of the question was fixed, because I don't think this is going to get any other responses. I appreciate the help.